# I don't know what is wrong? Some body help me

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
person.CustomerID as CustomerID,
address.Street as Street,

(
SELECT FROM Company comp
WHERE comp.Id = person.ID
AND entry_key = '_custComment' ) comp
,(SELECT FROM company comp
WHERE company.ID = person.ID
AND entry_key = '_otherInfo') other
Address addr, 
Person person
WHERE person.cid = custbasicinfo.cid
AND person.cid = addr.cid
```

Comment: what is your actual question? You should ask specifically and also provide some sample data , expected output so that people can answer to your question

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. This question is very unclear and will most likely be closed. You should try reading our How to ask section before posting it again, so we can actually help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't know whats wrong either without some more information, for instance, what error are you getting, what happens that is different that what you expect? Edit your question and add more information so we might be able to come up with an answer.

Comment: For one thing a sub query can only return 1 column AND you are not selecting any columns at all.AND you are missing FROM in you main query. I suggest you review your notes on the select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactically *correcter* and probably garbage..

```
SELECT
person.CustomerID as CustomerID,
address.Street as Street,
(SELECT a FROM Company comp WHERE comp.Id = person.ID AND entry_key = '_custComment' ) comp,
(SELECT a FROM company comp WHERE company.ID = person.ID AND entry_key = '_otherInfo') other
from Address addr, Person person
WHERE person.cid = custbasicinfo.cid AND person.cid = addr.cid
```